# Passing a dictionary or its keys as values to a function

Tags: python, dictionary

So I wrote a function that reads in a .csv file and creates a dictionary of abbreviations and their meaning. Now I'm looking to create a main function that calls the create dictionary function and then prompts the user for keys, but I'm not sure how to access the created dictionary.

```
import csv

def CreateDictionary(fileName):

    with open(fileName, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        newDict = {}
        for x, y in reader:
            newDict.setdefault(x, []).append(y)
        return newDict



def main():
    CreateDictionary('textToEnglish.csv')
    key = input("Please enter a text abbreviation")
    for key, value in newDict:
```

Comment: in CreateDictonary(), you create and populate newDict and return it, but your main function doesn't assign that return value to anything. why?

Comment: Didnt know I had too...Thought if it was returned, it was accessible.

Comment: Yup, the newDict variable is (basically) only available inside the function where it was created. This is called scope.

Comment: @KelvinDavis please see the [pep-8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-names) for python function naming conventions.  `CreateDictionary(_)` makes me cringe.

Comment: Will do, have to get use the change of naming convention compared to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to assign the return value of the `CreateDictionary` function to some variable like this:

```
newDict=CreateDictionary('textToEnglish.csv')
```

this way you can access the items in the dictionary like this:

```
newDict["etc"]
```

Comment: Follow-up question, would you happen to know why it would give me the error: ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @KelvinDavis are you using a split() somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You have to store the return value of `CreateDictionary` into a variable.

```
myDict = CreateDictionary('textToEnglish.csv')
```

By the way: You should rename the variable `key` because it will be overwritten in the `for` loop.